How to properly model the entities am i working with
I am developing an application which, among other things, defines the following entities:
There is a base class called "Action", with the following inheritors:
SimpleAction1, SimpleAction2 , BaseComplexAction.
BaseComplexAction is inherited by ComplexAction1, ComplexAction2
Then, there's is a generic interface called "Technique" whose generic type can be any class in the "Action" hierarchy.
"Technique" defines two methods:
getActions() which returns a concrete subtype of "Action" and matchesAction() which returns a Boolean.
matchesAction() is supposed to tell if a certain Action could have been generated by the concrete implementation of "Technique".
I'll add some example Java implementations of the classes above for reference:
interface Technique<T extends Action> {
    T getActions();
    boolean matchesAction(T action);
}

// Concrete Technique implementation
class MyTechnique implements Technique<BaseComplexAction> {
    @Override
    public BaseComplexAction getActions() {
        // Logic to determine and return a specific ComplexAction
        return new ComplexAction1();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matchesAction(BaseComplexAction action) {
        // Logic to check if the action matches the technique's criteria
        return action instanceof ComplexAction1;
    }
}

Different Techniques can yield the same concrete type of Action
With this structure, I am running into issues:

If someone wants to use the matches() method on a generic Action, it will be necessary to first cast the action to the correct type supported by the concrete Technique type.
Instead if I remove the generic type  from the definition of Technique, the concrete Technique will have to check the class type of the provided generic Action, and then cast it to the concrete subtype in order to perform the check

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to improve my class definitions to avoid casts and make the consumption of these methods smoother, if possible.
I'll be happy to provide more details if needed.

You can write a default implementation of matchesAction that takes an Action. This method will check if it the action is of the T type, and if it is, pass it on to the implementation that takes a T.
interface Technique<T extends Action> {
    Class<?> getSupportedType();

    T getActions();

    boolean matchesSupportedAction(T action);
    default boolean matchesAction(Action action) {
        if (getSupportedType().isInstance(action)) {
            return false;
        }
        return matchesSupportedAction((T)action);
    }
}

Note that since T is not available at runtime, you'd need an extra method getSupportedType to return a Class representing T.
With some simple assumptions, getSupportedType can be implemented as a default method too:
default Class<?> getSupportedType() {
    return Arrays.stream(getClass().getGenericInterfaces())
            .filter(x -> x instanceof ParameterizedType pt && 
                    pt.getRawType().equals(Technique.class) &&
                    pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0] instanceof Class<?>
            )
            .map(x -> (Class<?>)((ParameterizedType)x).getActualTypeArguments()[0])
            .findFirst()
            // this will be thrown when any of the assumptions we make are false
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UnsupportedOperationException("Please implement getSupportedType!"));
}


Hello and thank you for your answer. While i agree this is a viable solution, it still makes use of casting to solve the issue.
I was wondering if any refactoring of my class structure would allow me to avoid that altogether. But maybe it's just unfeasible
